# dhclient append settings from multiple DHCP servers

Tags: linux, dhcp, resolv.conf, dhclient

I have a server with two interfaces connected to two separate networks, using DHCP for both.  When dhclient is writing `/etc/resolv.conf`, I would like it to append settings that aren't already there.  For instance, if I receive from one DHCP server:

```
nameserver 10.0.0.1
search one.mydomain.com
```

and from another:

```
nameserver 10.1.1.254
search two.mydomain.com
```

Then resolv.conf should look like this:

```
search one.mydomain.com two.mydomain.com
nameserver 10.0.0.1
nameserver 10.1.1.254
```

At the moment, it seems the last dhclient overwrites whatever was there.  I know I can preconfigure settings in dhclient.conf using `supercede` or `append`, but then I have to hard-code the values.  I've scoured the man page for dhclient, but it seems like dhclient prefers to work alone (i.e. not in conjunction with any other dhclients)...or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, the most apropriate way is to use custom dhclient-script for each interface and write DNS parameters in separate files (i.e. /etc/resolv.d/eth[01]) and then call script that merges all these files in global /etc/resolv/conf

Comment: Something along those lines seems appropriate but this seems like a fundamentally very weird way to go about things.

Comment: Other way that I can see - patch or rewrite dhclient itself :) Using dhclient-script is a bit easier.

Comment: I'm thinking if the tools don't already exist to get two dhclients to work together, then it's probably easier to just statically assign both interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know dhclient doesn't support this since it's not smart enough to merge configs and it's something that most people don't make use of.

Your only option is to use `supercede` and `append` but since that doesn't do what you want you're pretty much in a not resolvable scenario.